# Can I sell/solicit my services by applying to regular job positions?

Tags: attracting-clients, sales

If you are an independent consultant/contractor, working for multiple clients, how do you sell your services? Do you apply to job offers for regular positions and offer your services to the hiring manager?

My opinion is that a contractor is a great idea to see if you really need to take in a full-time employee, and thought if I could explain this to managers they would be open.

Can I sell/solicit my services by applying to regular positions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do both. Usually the first contact with some company is applying for the job. Once you have done the job and the client is satisfied, I then ask him if he's willing to work with my team as well under my standards and my supervision.

Somehow, I don't think that approaching to the hiring manager directly would do much good since he does not know you. I, for example, instantly delete any email coming to my inbox where some anonymous is offering his services to me.

On the other hand, when I need a new team mate and an applicant says something like "I am applying to this position, but in case you need my colleague is expert in XY area as well so we both can work together" I will never delete him but will consider his team only if I am satisfied with his work on my project.

I guess many client think the same as myself.